# How to create an Android keystore RSA key with infinite validity?

Tags: android, rsa, keystore, android-keystore

Here is [how Google suggests creating an Android keystore](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert):

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name \
  -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

While 10000 days may seem like eternity, 27 years could pass quicker than you think, and RSA might still be in use.
If tweaking a command-line argument now has a 0.01% chance of saving my market share in the future, I am willing to do it.

**QUESTION:** How to make this validity period as long as possible?

Comment: use a larger value for validity? 1000000 will give you a key that expires in the year 4750. But actually 27 years is already extremely long for a crytographic algorithm to remain secure.

Comment: You really could answer this yourself by trial and error. Is 270 years long enough? How about 2700 years?

Comment: @GregS: Thanks, I edited the subject, please let me know if anything else does not make sense.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"1000 years" example:

I have created "1000 years" JKS keystore without problem as well:

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365000`

Then, checked for expiration period:

`keytool -list -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore`

```
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry
...
Valid from: Tue Aug 04 15:28:01 BST 2015 until: Mon Dec 05 14:28:01 GMT 3014
```

So, the key is valid until **Mon Dec 05 14:28:01 GMT 3014**

Comment: 1,000,000 days seems to work as well. But 10,000,000 days does not work.

Answer (score 23):

You should be able to create a key that will be valid for 292 billion years, if I did the math correctly.

I looked at the source for keytool, http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.java, and it looks like the validity period is stored in seconds, as a long.  The largest value a long can hold 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 is **9223372036854776000 seconds** which equals 106751991167300 days which equals 292,271,023,045 years.  There may be other factors that disallow such a large value, but this seems to be the max amount the tool can generate.

Comment: Python tells me that 2**63 - 1 is 9223372036854775807 (seconds), which equals 106751991167300 days.

Comment: `jarsigner` (the "official" command-line tool) crashes on a keystore I just created with a validity of 10,000,000 days. So while theoretically true, the practical answer is probably less.

Answer (score 4):

Doing some trial-and-error, I'm seeing a practical maximum around the year 9999.  As of today, with two keys created this way:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore year-9998.keystore -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 2914760

keytool -genkey -v -keystore year-10002.keystore -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 2916223
```

While both keys seem to create successfully, inspecting these keys with commands:

`keytool -list -v -keystore year-9998.keystore`

> Runs OK, giving "Valid from: Tue Aug 29 11:12:45 CDT 2017 until: Thu Jan 01 10:12:45 CST 9998"

`keytool -list -v -keystore year-10002.keystore`

> Crashes with "keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Parse Generalized time, invalid format"

So I think a practical maximum expiration is just before year 10000.

Answer (score 0):

I have created "1000 years" JKS keystore without problem as well:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365000
```

Then, checked for expiration period:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

Enter keystore password:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN
```

The output will be:

```
Your keystore contains 1 entry Valid from: Tue Aug 04 15:28
```

Comment: What is the problem now?